# Web frameworks oriented towards graph databases?

Tags: frameworks, graph, neo4j

I am to build a web app and I have realized that my domain data will be best represented by a graph structure. Which web frameworks out there does the greatest job at integrating with graph databases (neo4j in my case) and thereby gives me the easiest time getting up and running? I am open for all languages (mostly..)

EDIT:

My use case:

I am creating a bug tracker for a university department. It will track all kinds of issues (eg.: the classroom 1-0-24 needs chalk for the whiteboard, the course 'Introduction to programming sucks because of...', The alarm on the door into the library is way too strict, etc.)

I have defined loads of 'Areas of responsibility' (AoR) that are related to each other in terms of 'topically relatedness', 'is a super-AoR', 'is a sub-AoR', 'the responsible team is also responsible for this other AoR' and such. I want to present a graph of these areas of responsibility to the user. This is my wishlist for the graph:

- Initially only show a subset of the graph
- The user can pan around
- As the user pans in one direction, new areas of the graph is revealed.
- The user can click on a node to a) read more about that AoR, b) assign the users current Issue to that AoR (or maybe even drag issues to a AoR, just like with friends in Google+)

Currently I am considering using Grails (for the non-graphy parts like security and user management) and raw neo4j for the graph parts (that is, not using the GORM plugin that tries to fit a circle in a square hole)

I have now read about InfoGrid and it sounds quite interesting - especially the view-part (though I don't know how close it will bring me to my UX goal). I'm also worryed that it will not be as productive as Grails for the non-graphy parts.
Neo4j doesn't seem completely lost when it comes to visualisation either: 
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Visualization_options_for_graphs

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are looking for web frameworks which provides built in widgets for graph visualization. If this is true, than probably the best approach is to search for widgets provided by jquery plugins or similar. Integrating this kind of widgets still shouldn't be dependent on web framework you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InfoGrid project built its own web framework on top of the InfoGrid graph database -- precisely because existing web frameworks don't match graphs very well.

For example, we have custom tags for traversing (simple and compound) edges, detecting certain topologies, converting node identifiers into URLs etc.

Disagreeing with the other commenter, it would be so much harder (and so much less fun) to use a non-graph-aware web framework. We used to :-(

Comment: Traversing edges and detecting topologies shouldn' t live in web tier, it is rather a middle tier.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would describe your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Any web framework you'll choose, should be absolutely independent on the DB integration. From my experience, the best web framework is the one you know the best.

When choosing web frameworks, it is better to consider different criteria than DB integration, (like: public vs intranet application, statless vs statefull model, number of expected concurrent users, etc).